# Rails does not translate my {{key}} anymore from my lang files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've updated Rails and now I all the {{key}} that I had in my lang files are not translated anymore.

Ex:
hello: Hello {{name}}

would be displayed as "Hello {{name}}" instead of "Hello John" when calling t(:hello).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `hello: Hello %{name}` instead.

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#interpolation